# JQuery - Problemas com função de editar checkbox

Tags: jquery

Estou com um problema na funcão do botão editar. Consigo editar a primeira palavra da forma correta, mas qunado clico em editar uma checkbox, além de editar esse texto. O outro textp também é editado. E assim por diante. Todas os textos são editados ao invés de somente o texto que foi clicado.

```
<body>

        <section> 
            <h2>Check Box</h2>
            <div id="lista">
                <form>
                    <div>
                        <input id="teste" name="teste" type="checkbox" class="normal">
                        <label for="teste"  >Teste</label>             
                        <a class="remove" href="#">Remover</i></a> 
                        <a class="edit" href="#">Editar</i></a>


                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="add_box"> 
                <input id="adicionarTxt" type="text">
                <button id="adicionarBtn">Adicionar</button>
            </div>
            <div class="edit_box"> 
                <input id="editarTxt" type="text">
                <button id="editarBtn">Editar</button>
                <button id="backBtn"><i class="fas fa-undo"></i></button>
            </div>

             <div class="controler"> 
                <button id="checkAll">CheckAll</button>
                <button id="Uncheck">Uncheck all</button>
                <button id="inverter">Inverter Seleção</button>  
            </div>
        </section>

        <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
```

```
//-----------------------------Adicionar Elemento 
var cont=0;
$('#adicionarBtn').on('click', function(){
    if ($('#adicionarTxt').val()) {
    var conteudo = $('#adicionarTxt').val().padStart(25, " ");
    /*$('#lista form').append('<div><input id="'+ cont +'" type="checkbox" name="'+ cont +'" class="normal"><label for="'+ cont +'" data-target="'+ cont +'">'+ conteudo +'</label><a class="remove" href="#"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a><a class="edit" href="#" data-click="'+ cont +'"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>');*/
     $('#lista form')
     .append($('<div>')
            .append($("<input>", {
                    id: cont,
                    type: "checkbox",
                    name: cont,
                    class: "normal"}))
            .append($("<label>", {
                    for: cont,
                    "data-target": cont,
                    text: conteudo}))
            .append($("<a>", {
                    class: "remove",
                    href: "#"})
            .append($("<i>", {class: "far fa-trash-alt"})))
            .append($("<a>", {
                    class: "edit",
                    href: "#",
                    "data-click": cont})
            .append($("<i>", {class: "fas fa-pencil-alt"}))));
    console.log(conteudo + " Adicionado!");
    salvarLocalStorage();
    $("#adicionarTxt").val("");
    cont++;
  }
});

//-----------------------------Editar Elemento 
$(document).on('click','.edit',function(){
    var $target = $(this).prev().prev();  



    $('.add_box').hide();
    $('.edit_box').show();

    $(document).on('click','#editarBtn', function(){
        var edit = $('#editarTxt').val();

        $target.text(edit);
        $('.edit_box').hide();
        $('.add_box').show();
    })

    $('#backBtn').on('click',function(){
        $('.edit_box').hide();
        $('.add_box').show();
    })

});
```

Comment: O código só mostra um checkbox.

Comment: Acho que você está confundindo a terminologia dentro do jargão de TI. Entendo que o verbo editar para algumas profissões significa apagar e para outras significa produzir, dentro do jargão da informática significa fazer modificações. De uma revisada no texto de sua pergunta, pois está vago.

Comment: Modifiquei a pergunta adicinando a função "Adicionar", acredito que agora esteja certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao usar `.on()` dentro de `.on()` irá criar e acumular os `.on()` aninhados cada vez que o `.on()` principal for disparado, ou seja, ao clicar em `.edit` a primeira vez irá criar os dois eventos `.on()` aninhados. No segundo clica irá criar mais dois, e no terceiro click o evento em `$(document).on('click','#editarBtn'...` e o `$('#backBtn').on('click'...` serão disparados duas vezes e assim por diante.

Por isso o ideal é usar event handlers separados e não aninhados. No seu caso, percebe-se que você fez isso por causa da variável `$target`, que é gerada no `$(document).on('click','.edit'...` e usada no `$(document).on('click','#editarBtn'...`.

Neste caso, você pode corrigir o funcionamento usando o método `.one()` no lugar de `.on()` nos event handlers aninhados, porque o `.one()` só é executado 1 vez, o que evita a acumulação na memória e que esses eventos sejam disparados mais de uma vez:

```
$(document).on('click','.edit',function(){
    var $target = $(this).prev().prev();  

    $('.add_box').hide();
    $('.edit_box').show();

   $(document).one('click','#editarBtn', function(){ // .one()
     var edit = $('#editarTxt').val();

     $target.text(edit);
     $('.edit_box').hide();
     $('.add_box').show();
   })

   $('#backBtn').one('click',function(){ // .one()
     $('.edit_box').hide();
     $('.add_box').show();
   })

});
```